# How to add common UIButton at the bottom on my all view instead of tabsview controller in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwindow

I want to put `UIbutton` at bottom which should be displayed on my all view like tabBar and `onclick` of that `UIButton` I want open the menu view, How can achieve this feature, I tried lot for this and also lot of google search for it, but not mention the way to achieve this properly, So please suggest me the the proper way to achieve this

[image: This image contain at bottom one 'Team' button, onclick of that 'Team' the menu view should open look next screen shot for that]

[image: The black view contaning menu should open]

Comment: you can Use 
1. http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/pushback-animation-view

Comment: 2. http://code4app.net/ios/Expandable-TabBar/4f8b96aa06f6e78e35000001

Comment: 3.http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/knsemimodalview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this before by adding a button in the Appdelegate class. I don't know whether it's a correct approach or not, but it's working.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    viewController = [[SUSAViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SUSAViewController" bundle:nil];

    nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = nav;

    UIButton *mybtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    mybtn.frame=CGRectMake(40, 200, 200, 200);
    [mybtn setTitle:@"My Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [nav.view addSubview:mybtn];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

If you are not using `NavigationController` then simply add `[self.window addSubview:mybtn];`
Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a BaseViewController that contains just that button and its menu items?

Then if you get all your view controllers to inherit from that BaseViewController, then all your View Controllers will have that button.

```
// import your custom menu view
#import "CustomMenuView.h"

@interface BaseViewController : UIViewController
{
    UIButton *btnMenu;
    CustomMenuView *customMenu;
}

@end 

...

// Now tell your other view controllers to inherit from the base view controller
#import "BaseViewController.h"

@interface YourOtherViewController: BaseViewController
{

}

@end
```

Using Inheritance, all your View Controllers should now have that button and the menu in place.